# How to implement open street map on android with infowindow on markers?

Tags: java, android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

How to implement open street map on android with infowindow on markers?

```
OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        openStreetMap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
        openStreetMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        openStreetMapController = openStreetMap.getController();
        openStreetMapController.setZoom(16);
        openStreetMap.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    GeoPoint initialLocation = new GeoPoint(lat , lng);
    centerMap(initialLocation);
    addLocation(lat ,lng , R.drawable.marker);}
```

This is my code and y want to add markers with it's infoWindows like googleMaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample using marker was recently added. The original source is from [osmbonuspack's tutorial](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0)

The sample is located [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/data/SampleMarker.java)

The basic code is this

`GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(38.8977, -77.0365);  //white house
        Marker startMarker = new Marker(mMapView);
        startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        startMarker.setTitle("White House");
        startMarker.setSnippet("The White House is the official residence and principal workplace of the President of the United States.");
        startMarker.setSubDescription("1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500");
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
        mMapView.invalidate();`

Answer (score 1):

The [osmdroid wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki) contains a guide called [How to use the osmdroid library](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library). It contains a section about [placing icons on the map with a click listener](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library#how-do-i-place-icons-on-the-map-with-a-click-listener).

Basically you have to create a `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus` consisting of `OverlayItem`s. Each `OverlayItem` comes with a title, a description and of course coordinates. The `ItemizedOverlayWithFocus` has to be added to your `MapView`.

There is the example from the wiki page:

```
//your items
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
items.add(new OverlayItem("Title", "Description", new GeoPoint(0.0d,0.0d))); // Lat/Lon decimal degrees

//the overlay
ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem> mOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(items,
    new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
    //do something
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});
mOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);

mMapView.getOverlays().add(mOverlay);
```